# PROPFIND 405 error on IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, webdav, iis-8.5

I'm currently trying to send a PROPFIND request to my IIS 8.5 server, but everytime I do so I get the error "405 Method not allowed". I hope you can help me.

I already googled the issue and unfortunately none of the solution I found could solve my issue.

I already checked my applicationHost.config and to me it looks that all settings are correct.
[image: applicationHost config handler]
[image: applicationHost config verbs]
[image: applicationHost config propfind auth]
I also tried to add WebDAV directly to my web.config:
[image: config handler]
Lastly I enabled Failed Request Tracing and got the following:
[image: error trace]

**Edit:** The relevant parts of the config files:

applicationHost.config

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
            <add name="WebDAV" path="*" verb="PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,MKCOL,PUT,COPY,DELETE,MOVE,LOCK,UNLOCK" modules="WebDAVModule" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />

...

<verbs allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true">
    <add verb="TRACE" allowed="false" />
</verbs>

...

<webdav>
    <authoring>
        <properties allowAnonymousPropfind="true" allowInfinitePropfindDepth="true" />
    </authoring>
</webdav>
```

web.config

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
    <add name="WebDAV" path="*" verb="PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,MKCOL,PUT,COPY,DELETE,MOVE,LOCK,UNLOCK" modules="WebDAVModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\webdav.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
</handlers>
```

And the text of the trace:

```
Event        MODULE_WARNING
ModuleName   WebDAVModule
Data1        WebDAV Disabled
ErrorCode    The operation completed successfully.(0x0)

Event          MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
ModuleName     WebDAVModule 
Notification   MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER 
HttpStatus     405 
HttpReason     Method Not Allowed 
HttpSubStatus  0 
ErrorCode      The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: Can you replace the images with the ecorresponding texts, if they are needed, or remove them? They do not help, as in the notepad windows, you see horizontal sliders (so not everything is visible for us), and the error message is unreadable small

Comment: @NicoHaase I added the texts.

Comment: There are four relevant config files, each of which can contain a <handlers> section. Besides the two files the OP mentioned, there are also the machine.config and web.config files in a directory such as c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\. Carefully review each entry in each of the four files' <handlers> sections to see which other handlers might be interfering. In my case, the problem wasn't another handler. My website's web.config file's <handlers> section contains <clear />, which cancels the standard WebDAV config that's in applicationHost.config.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.
The solution was simple, just enabling WebDAV for the website.
Somehow, in IIS, WebDAV is disabled by default for each separate web site. After opening the feature WebDAV Authoring Rules, you have the option to enable it (or disable ...)